# How to use multiple programming languages in one GTK application?

Tags: c++, gtk, glib, gtkmm, gobject

I am currently learning GTK, specifically gtkmm. As i can see GTK has excellent support in different languages through bindings. So one can use c, c++, js, python and more to implement gtk apps. Thats great. But what if i wanted to create one application, say the base window and some api objects/instances in gtkmm and c++ and want to let others create modules in any other language that has gtk binding. I want to share the api objects/instances (say they are singletons) between all modules. But i definitely don't want to spawn multiple processes for this to work. I know boost has support for exposing c++ objects into python modules. I am looking for something like that. But from the documentation so far (i haven't finished it yet, so forgive me if i have missed anything), i couldn't find the proper way to do that.

Comment: If your main window (and maybe other widgets) are implemented in C++, and you want that Python code may integrate other widgets into them, so you have to embed a Python interpreter and you have to expose your C++ instances in Python, e.g. defining resp. Python variables with the values from C++ (before you start the interpretation of users Python code), so that your C++ widgets become "visible" inside Python. (Instead of Python variables, you could define/expose Python functions as well, of course.)

Comment: Yes, that can be done with boost python quite easily. But what about other languages like js ? Is there anyway to do the same between c++ and gjs (as i am trying to utilize gtk, i am talking about gjs here) ?

Comment: Maybe you could use middleware? I don't thik gtk has something for this.